# How to have multiple tablix with same data table in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a table contains savings benefit and insurance benefit of all employee.
all the employee records will be stored in employee table.

I need to display all the insurance and savings of each employee in RDLC report.

I need to have two tablix one with insurance tablix  and another with savings tablix.

If an employee doesnt have insurance benefit and have a saving benefit.

Then insurance tablix should be hidden and needs to display only saving tablix.

How can we acheive this in rdlc report.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I think you should show what you have tried.